# Express as either LP, QP, QCQP or SOCP

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, quadratic-programming, second-order-cone-programming

I have a problem which needs to be expressed as either LP, QP, QCQP or SOCP.
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimise}_{x,y,t}  & a||\mathbf{x}||_2^2 + b||\mathbf{y}||_2^2 \\
\text{subject to}& ||\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}||_2^2 \le t.
\end{array}
Its given that $a,b \in \mathbb{R}_+$ and $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I tried to express it as SOCP by opening up the equations.

\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimise}_{x,y,t}  & \sum_i^n ax_i^2+by_i^2 \\
\text{subject to}& \sum_1^n(x_i+y_i)^2 \le t \iff \sum_i^n(x^2_i+ y_i^2) \le t.
\end{array}

I am not sure how to proceed further, as the objective is still not affine/linear.

Or is it better to try for QCQP as,
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimise}_{x,y,t}  & a\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x} + b\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{y} \\
\text{subject to}& (\mathbf{x+y})^T (\mathbf{x+y}) \le t \iff  \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{y} + 2\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{y} \le t.
\end{array}.

I am right in my formulations ? How to I proceed further ? I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Both your objective and constraint are (convex) quadratic. This is a convex QCQP. There is a standard trick for turning it into SOCP. In general, you have a convex quadratic constraint $x^T P x + 2q^T x + r \leq t$, where $P$ is positive semidefinite. Let $P = M^T M$ be the Gram decomposition. Write the constraint as $x^T M^T M x \leq t - r - 2q^T x$. This is a rotated second-order cone constraint. It can be rewritten in the form $\Big\| \begin{pmatrix} 2 M x \\ t - r - 2q^T x - 1  \end{pmatrix} \Big\| \leq t - r - 2q^T x + 1$. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: To relate my previous comment to your specific problem: The constraint $\|x + y\|^2 \leq t$ can be rewritten as $\Big\| \begin{pmatrix}  2(x + y) \\ t - 1 \end{pmatrix} \Big\| \leq t + 1$.

Comment: @nowhere Thank you for your comment. As I understand from your comments, the latter formulation in the original post is correct. Your generalization for converting it into SOCP is also very good and I understood that. But, you have defined it for a single optimization variable. I'm sure how you got it for multiple optimizing variables, as it is here. Specifically, what manipulations do you do to the constraint $x^Tx + y^Ty+2x^Ty \le t$ to get what you got. I imagine something similar has to be done to make the objective affine ?

Comment: Your $\iff$ for SOCP is not correct.  You have omitted the $x_i y_i$ terms.

Comment: @Craig Wilder By "multiple optimization variables", you emphasize that $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are vectors, not scalars, correct? $\Big\| \begin{pmatrix}2(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y}) \\ t - 1\end{pmatrix}\Big\| \leq t + 1$ still works. The notation $\begin{pmatrix} 2(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y}) \\ t  - 1\end{pmatrix}$ means a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n + 1}$. You check (by directly squaring $\Big\| \begin{pmatrix}2(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y}) \\ t - 1\end{pmatrix}\Big\|$ and $t + 1$), that this condition is equivalent to $\|\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y}\|^2 \leq t$.

Comment: @Craig Wilder The general trick you want to use is the following: If you have optimization variables $\mathbf{w} \in \mathbb{R}^n, u, v \in \mathbb{R}$, then you can express constraint $\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{w} \leq uv, u \geq 0, v \geq 0$ equivalently as $\Big\| \begin{pmatrix} 2\mathbf{w} \\ u - v\end{pmatrix} \Big\| \leq u + v$. (Check it by directly squaring both sides). In your case, I made the substitution $\mathbf{w} = \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y}$, $u = t$, $v = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an SOCP reformulation.  Introduce variable $z \ge 0$ to represent $a ||x||_2^2 + b ||y||_2^2$.  Introduce variable $u \ge 0$ to represent $||x+y||_2^2$. Introduce variable $v$ to represent the constant $1/2$. Introduce variable $w_i$ to represent $x_i + y_i$.  The problem is to minimize $z$ subject to
\begin{align}
u &\le t \\
v &= 1/2 \\
w_i &= x_i + y_i &&\text{for all $i$} \\
2 u v &\ge \sum_i w_i^2 \\
2 v z &\ge \sum_i \left((\sqrt{a} x_i)^2 + (\sqrt{b} y_i)^2\right)                                   
\end{align}
The last two constraints are rotated SOC constraints, and everything else is linear.

Note that $x_i=y_i=t=0$ is optimal.